# Exception handling when changing Pandas dataframe type

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with a single column of strings. I want to convert the column data to float. Some of the values cannot be converted to float due to their format. I want to omit these "illegal strings" from the result and only extract values that can be legally re-cast as floats. The starting data:

```
test=pd.DataFrame()
test.loc[0,'Value']='<3'
test.loc[1,'Value']='10'
test.loc[2,'Value']='Detected'
test.loc[3,'Value']=''
```

The desired output contains only strings that could be re-cast as floats (in this case, 10):

```
cleanDF=test['Value'].astype(float)
cleanDF
0    10
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Of course, this throws an error as expected on the illegal string for float conversion:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: <3
```

Is there a simple way to solve this if the dataframe is large and contains many illegal strings in 'Value'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using DataFrame's `apply`.  Write a function that includes an exception handler and apply it to the DataFrame.

```
def test_apply(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return None

cleanDF = test['Value'].apply(test_apply).dropna()
```

Comment: Thanks. To make the solution generally applicable to DataFrames with multiple columns, I suppose returning an error flag (e.g., 'fail') and slicing the DataFrame is reasonable. But perhaps more elegant approaches. `test.loc[test['Value'].apply(test_apply)!='Fail',:]`

Comment: this is pretty inefficient; better to do: ``test['Value'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dropna()``

Comment: Indeed. Ended up using this approach for multi-column DataFrames: `test.loc[~np.isnan(test['Value'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)),:]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `errors=coerce` with the `apply` method.

So first convert anything that can be converted to numeric, then drop `NaN` values, finally convert to float

```
cleanDF = test.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce').dropna().astype(float)
```

which returns only the values and the data type that you want

```
>>> cleanDF['Value']

cleanDF['Value']
1    10.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: It will be quite inefficient to use apply on a large dataset, you should use:
`pd.to_numeric(test['Value'], errors = "coerce")` instead